# Mimic HTML5 form validation default styling

Tags: css, forms, html, validation

I have a simple HTML5 form with required fileds. When the page loads the fields have no styling. When I click on the required field, type something and then erase the text I just typed and exit the field, it shows me pink box-shadow outside the invalid field in Firefox.

Now I need yellow box-shadow, while retaining the same behavior. That's how I did:

**In HTML**

```
<input name="email_address" id="email_address_uuid_479823574" type="email"
       placeholder="ex. example@domain.com" title="Email address" required />

       -------
       -------

<input name="model_number" id="model_number_uuid_479823574" type="text"
       placeholder="ex. oxpd-983s" title="Equipment model number" required />
```

**In CSS**

```
input:required:invalid {box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px yellow};
```

Result: The page loads with all the fields with yellow box-shadow! Rather wait for user to make the mistake onblur and onsubmit like the default behavior.

How to override the default box-shadow of invalid field **without changing the behavior**?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
input:required:-moz-ui-invalid {box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px yellow};
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:invalid

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works in Firefox but what about other browsers? Is there any such pseudo-selector in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: @JasonWilliams I thought the problem was in firefox

Comment: I have tested in other browsers as well. Ofcourse the website is supposed to be compatible with *all* browsers.

Comment: Ah ok. But not all browsers support html5, let alone the html5 validation. I couldn't find anything for webkit, sorry.